# Recursively divide image and process in parallel

Tags: c++, image-processing, parallel-processing, mpi

I need to perform certain trivial operations on an image (negative in this case). I'm told that I need to recursively divide the image in equal rectangles, and process them in parallel using MPI..

I wrote a function for doing this in my sequential image processing class:

```
void recursive_negative_helper(int x, int y, int WIDTH, int HEIGHT)
{
    /* recurse until dimensions become odd, to avoid corruption of image
      (equal sized rectangles only) */
    if( (WIDTH&1) || (HEIGHT&1) )
    {
        uint8_t color[BPP];
        for(int i=y ; i<y+HEIGHT ; i++)
        {
            for(int j=x ; j<x+WIDTH ; j++)
            {
                    get_pixel(color,i,j);
                    for(int k=0 ; k<BPP ; k++)
                        color[k] = 255-color[k];
                    set_pixel(color,i,j);
            }
        }
        return;
    }
    recursive_negative_helper(x        , y         , WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2);
    recursive_negative_helper(x+WIDTH/2, y         , WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2);
    recursive_negative_helper(x        , y+HEIGHT/2, WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2);
    recursive_negative_helper(x+WIDTH/2, y+HEIGHT/2, WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2);
}

void recursive_negative()
{
    recursive_negative_helper(0,0,width,height);
}
```

I'm learning MPI for the first time and having a hard time figuring out how to do this in parallel. I guess one way is dividing in 4 and giving each part to a process. That would be enough for my application! But how can I do it for any number of processes?

Can anyone help? Also if possible, please post some MPI pseudocode, so that I can visualize it more clearly!

Comment: Clarify whether MPI is really a must (seems unlikely since you haven't included a single MPI line there), or something relatively more simple like OpenMP would be enough ? Also, there many examples around. Haven't you seen any of them ?

Comment: Though this is theoretically a elegant way of solving this problem, it might not prove to be so in practice. If you are working on sufficiently large images(2^m X 2^n), the program might just crash saying that you have run out of stack space (max recursion depth reached)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest to use OPENMP (http://openmp.org/wp/) to do parallel processing, for your case. It is easy to configure and compile to optimize simple loops. The code change is also trivial. But I am not sure about the recursion handling so be careful about it, or just use an non-recursive implementation.
Some tutorials and guide: http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/